# nearest date in php strtotime

Tags: php, date

I have several date(strtotime) in a Variable and want the first nearest date that is after the specified date(my date) with php. what do i do?

**Variable:**

```
$varD = "1481691600,1482642000,1482037200";
```

**my date:**

```
1481778000 => (2016-12-15)
```

**several date(strtotime):**

```
1481691600 => (2016-12-14)
1482642000 => (2016-12-25)
1482037200 => (2016-12-18) //result
```

**result:**

```
1482037200 => (2016-12-18)
```

Comment: explode on `,` to get the dates into an array and then loop over and compare them. Find the `min` date that is `>` your target date.

Answer (score 1):

```
$varD = "1481691600,1482037200,1482642000";
$myDate = "1481778000";
```

After you `explode` the string of timestamps (`$varD`), you can filter them and return the minimum value of the result. Here is one way to do that using `array_filter` and `min`.

```
$comp = function($x) use ($myDate) { return $x > $myDate; };

$firstDateAfterYours = min(array_filter(explode(',', $varD), $comp));
```

---

But if you already know that the timestamps in the string will be in ascending order, it will probably be faster not to convert the whole thing to an array and sort through it. You can use `strtok` to go through it piece by piece and just stop as soon as you get to a timestamp larger than your target.

```
$ts = strtok($varD, ',');
while ($ts !== false) {
    $ts = strtok(',');
    if ($ts > $myDate) break;
}
$firstDateAfterYours = $ts;
```